# What about if we want to know whether now at current time is morning, or afternoon or night?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

How to do so with NSDate?

All NSDate give is the GMT time. I want my time. I want the time my users see on their watch.

I want to display different pictures based on what time of the day it is.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`. The following code shows how to get the current hour and minute in your local timezone:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                 initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
int hour = [dateComponents hour];
int minute = [dateComponents minute];
```